# What makes an analog modem pickup an inbound call

Tags: 12.04, networking, modem, serial-port

I have a series of Modems connected to Ubuntu 12.04 3.2.0-23-generic-pae via a PCI-E card and the system recognizes them as **ttyS0, ttyS4, ttyS5, ttyS7**

No matter what the serial connection is, ttys4, 5, 6, etc... the second modem will never pickup the inbound call. I was able to connect a modem on another ubuntu machine to "Bridge the gap" but this proved inconvenient to people that had to work around it and created a trip hazard with phone cords running everywhere.

**ttyS0** receives a call from the huntgroup and picks up the call and communicates with its external site or url (converting from dial to IP, good job ttys0).

**ttyS4** only rings and rings and will not pickup the inbound calls causeing errors on actual equipment dialing inbound (connect error).

***If*** **ttyS4** is busy at the time of another inbound call, the huntgroup will kick over to the next available phone number which is connected to **ttyS5**

**ttyS5**will pickup the inbound call as it is designed.
 a few outputs ?

```
pax@W-Ubuntu-1:~$ **dmesg | grep ttyS**
[    1.392465] serial8250: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    1.776715] 00:07: ttyS0 at I/O 0x3f8 (irq = 4) is a 16550A
[    1.812483] 0000:03:02.0: ttyS4 at I/O 0xdcc8 (irq = 18) is a 16550A
[    1.848373] 0000:03:02.0: ttyS5 at I/O 0xdcd0 (irq = 18) is a 16550A
[    1.884332] 0000:03:02.0: ttyS6 at I/O 0xdcd8 (irq = 18) is a 16550A
[    1.920327] 0000:03:02.0: ttyS7 at I/O 0xdce0 (irq = 18) is a 16550A
```

and a `lspci`

```
Decided to use linux-sysfs
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express DRAM Controller (rev 0a)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31/P35/P31 Express PCI Express Root Port (rev 0a)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0a)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0a)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GB/GR (ICH7 Family) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801G (ICH7 Family) IDE Controller (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family SATA Controller [IDE mode] (rev 01)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller (rev 01)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5784M Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 10)
03:02.0 Serial controller: NetMos Technology PCI 9845 Multi-I/O Controller (rev 01)
```

The last line 03:02.0 is the pci card.

S.O.S.  this thing is giving me migraines.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your modem is not configured for auto-answering?

Register 0 in a standard Hayes-command-compatible modem stores the number of rings before the modem will answer. If this value is 0, then there's no auto-answer.

Furthermore, there is a way to store configuration as default, so perhaps your modem's config was altered to this value of 0 and the config stored.

So using a terminal program such as minicom, connect to the troublesome modem's port, and you could ask the modem about this value:

```
ATS0?
```

if this value is 0, then set it to, say, 2 rings:

```
ATS0=2
```

then save the configuration (to profile 0):

```
AT&W0
```

and then tell the modem to use this on powerup:

```
AT&Y0
```

It's been a while so I don't guarantee this will work. Read more here: http://michaelgellis.tripod.com/modem.html

Comment: I would attempt but it appears to always be the second modem.  no matter what modem is connected, or what ttys is assigned next in the config (.ini) file.

Comment: roadmr: trip down to memory lane... @cjmiller00: is it the NetMos Technology PCI 9845 Multi-I/O Controller that connects these 4 modems to the server?  If yes, can we have the full output of `dmesg`?